# Grid view builder not expanding by using Expanded widget in Flutter

Tags: flutter, dart, dart-pub

grid view builder, In this section I want to expand the grid view height as the available space for different size of phone height increase and other items height remains fixed but Expanded widget isn't working, making whole ui blank.

How can I make my grid view expandable as the height vary? I tried multiple solutions but didn't work.

1. Drawer
2. AppBar
3. Body - Slider, List-View, Grid-View
4. BottomNavigationBar

   ```
    @override
      Widget build(BuildContext context) {
       Size size = MediaQuery.of(context).size;
       return Scaffold(
          drawer: DrawerMenu(),
          appBar: PostHomeAppBar(appBar: AppBar()),
          body: Stack(
           children: [
            Container(
             height: double.infinity,
             width: double.infinity,
             decoration: const BoxDecoration(
            image: DecorationImage(
                image: AssetImage("lib/assets/asset/bg-original (1).png"),
                fit: BoxFit.cover)),
             child: Column(
              children: [
               Column(
                children: [
                ///slider
                Container(
                  height: size.height * 0.25,
                  width: double.infinity,
                  child: MySlider(),
                ),

                const SizedBox(
                  height: 5,
                ),

                ///list view builder
                Container(
                  height: 55,
                  child: ListView.builder(
                      scrollDirection: Axis.horizontal,
                      itemCount: _homePageController
                              .getGameCategorylist?.data?.length ??
                          0,
                      itemBuilder: (BuildContext context, int index) {
                        bool isSelected = _selectedTabIndex == index;
                        return Obx(
                          () => (_homePageController.isLoading.value)
                              ? const Center(child: Loader())
                              : _homePageController
                                          .getGameCategorylist!.data ==
                                      null
                                  ? const Center(
                                      child: Text(''),
                                    )
                                  : Padding(
                                      padding: const EdgeInsets.only(
                                          left: 2,
                                          right: 2,
                                          top: 4,
                                          bottom: 8),
                                      child: GestureDetector(
                                        onTap: () {
                                          _onTappedItem(index);
                                        },
                                        child: FittedBox(
                                          child: Container(
                                            padding: const EdgeInsets.only(
                                                left: 10, right: 10),
                                            decoration: BoxDecoration(
                                              color: isSelected
                                                  ? AppColors.golden
                                                  : null,
                                              gradient: isSelected
                                                  ? null
                                                  : const LinearGradient(
                                                      colors: [
                                                        Color(0xff1e1b53),
                                                        Color(0xff444185)
                                                      ],
                                                      begin: Alignment
                                                          .topCenter,
                                                      end: Alignment
                                                          .bottomCenter,
                                                    ),
                                              borderRadius:
                                                  BorderRadius.circular(30),
                                            ),
                                            child: Column(children: [
                                              SizedBox(
                                                height: size.height * 0.01,
                                              ),
                                              Text(
                                                _homePageController
                                                    .getGameCategorylist!
                                                    .data![index]
                                                    .lobbyCat
                                                    .toString(),
                                                textAlign: TextAlign.center,
                                                style: const TextStyle(
                                                    fontWeight:
                                                        FontWeight.w400,
                                                    color: Colors.white,
                                                    fontFamily: 'Roboto',
                                                    fontSize: 8),
                                              ),
                                              Text(
                                                '(${_homePageController.getGameCategorylist!.data![index].length.toString()})',
                                                textAlign: TextAlign.center,
                                                style: const TextStyle(
                                                    fontWeight:
                                                        FontWeight.w400,
                                                    color: Colors.white,
                                                    fontFamily: 'Roboto',
                                                    fontSize: 8),
                                              ),
                                              SizedBox(
                                                height: size.height * 0.005,
                                              ),
                                            ]),
                                          ),
                                        ),
                                      ),
                                    ),
                        );
                      }),
                ),

                ///grid view builder
                Expanded(
                  child: GridView.builder(
                    padding: EdgeInsets.zero,
                    gridDelegate:
                        const SliverGridDelegateWithFixedCrossAxisCount(
                      crossAxisCount: 2,
                      crossAxisSpacing: 2,
                      mainAxisSpacing: 2,
                      mainAxisExtent: 120,
                    ),
                    itemCount: casinoGameList?.data?.length ?? 0,
                    itemBuilder: (BuildContext context, int index) {
                      return Obx(() => (_homePageController.isLoading.value)
                          ? const Center(child: Loader())
                          : casinoGameList?.data == null
                              ? const Center(
                                  child: Text(''),
                                )
                              : GestureDetector(
                                  onTap: () {
                                    final gameData =
                                        casinoGameList?.data?[index];
                                    Get.to(() =>
                                        WebViewHome(gameData ?? Datum()));
                                  },
                                  child: Padding(
                                    padding: const EdgeInsets.all(4.0),
                                    child: Container(
                                      alignment: Alignment.center,
                                      decoration: BoxDecoration(
                                        borderRadius:
                                            BorderRadius.circular(10),
                                        image: DecorationImage(
                                          image: NetworkImage(base +
                                              '${casinoGameList?.data?[index].imgSrc.toString()}'),
                                          fit: BoxFit.cover,
                                        ),
                                      ),
                                    ),
                                  ),
                                ));
                    },
                  ),
                ),
              ],
            ),
          ],
        ),
      ),
      if (_isLoading)
        Padding(
          padding: EdgeInsets.only(top: 200),
          child: const Positioned.fill(
            child: Loader(),
          ),
        ),
     ],
     ),
     bottomNavigationBar: BottomNavigationBar(
      backgroundColor: const Color(0xff140b36),
      currentIndex: _currentIndex,
      onTap: (int index) {
      setState(() {
        _currentIndex = index;
      });
    },
    selectedItemColor: Colors.amber,
    unselectedItemColor: Colors.grey,
    type: BottomNavigationBarType.fixed,
    items: [
      BottomNavigationBarItem(
        icon: GestureDetector(
          onTap: () {
            Get.to(() => Home_Post_Login());
          },
          child: Image.asset('lib/assets/asset/icon_home_fill.png',
              color: _currentIndex == 0 ? Colors.amber : Colors.white,
              height: 20),
        ),
        label: 'HOME',
      ),
      BottomNavigationBarItem(
        icon: GestureDetector(
          onTap: () {
            Get.to(() => Login_Screen());
          },
          child: Image.asset('lib/assets/asset/icon_games.png',
              color: _currentIndex == 1 ? Colors.amber : Colors.white,
              height: 20),
        ),
        label: 'PROVIDERS',
      ),
      BottomNavigationBarItem(
        icon: GestureDetector(
          onTap: () {
            Get.to(() => WebViewHome(Datum(gameTypeUnified: 'game_shows')));
          },
          child: Image.asset('lib/assets/asset/icon_game_show.png',
              color: _currentIndex == 2 ? Colors.amber : Colors.white,
              height: 20),
        ),
        label: 'GAME SHOWS',
      ),
      BottomNavigationBarItem(
        icon: GestureDetector(
          onTap: () {
            Get.to(() => Profile());
          },
          child: Image.asset('lib/assets/asset/icon_user.png',
              color: _currentIndex == 3 ? Colors.amber : Colors.white,
              height: 20),
        ),
        label: 'MY ACCOUNT',
      ),
     ],
     ),
    );
   }
   ```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I noticed you are using two columns unnecessarily
here

```
image: DecorationImage(
             image: AssetImage("lib/assets/asset/bg-original (1).png"),
             fit: BoxFit.cover)),
          child: Column(
           children: [
            Column(
             children: [
             ///slider
```

It seems that Expanded is having trouble determining its size because the inner column does not have a size of its own. To address this issue, you have two options:

1. You can remove one of the columns if you don't require it.
2. Alternatively, you can wrap the inner column with Expanded if you truly need both columns.

Comment: I removed one of the parent Column and then it's works fine. Thank very much

Answer (score 0):

I think the error is because of that your gridView items do not have a bounded height, try to give them a height and see if it works or not

Comment: I try updating the height but its not worked. Can you please provide more context.

Answer (score 0):

use `shrinkWrap: true` property for **GridView** and remove the parent widget **Expanded**.

Comment: It's not working, freezes scrolling and bottom over flowed.